# VCAP - Where can i access the deployed applications's files on VCAP

Tags: cloud-foundry

I would like to know the location on VCAP where I can find the complete directory structure od any deployed application. I am aware that the same can be accessed via vmc fles  but I would like to know the physical location where the application files are stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it - the application file structure is available at /var/vcap.local/dea/apps